# unknown Method in xPath run by VBScript

Tags: xpath, vbscript, msxml

the error message is

> msxml3.dll: Unknown method.
>
> /Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/ServiceEvent[-->last()<--]/Service/Comment

My code looks like this and the error is on the case `NEW`

Case `OLD` works fine with `[0]` in there

```
'On Error Resume Next

Public Function GetParameterXml()
 GetParameterXml = _
 "<Parameters>" &_
  "<Parameter Value='Age' Code='A' Description='Age' Type='Combo' Tooltip='Would you like the newest or oldest Reason?'>" &_
   "    <Options>" &_
    " <Option Code='O' Description='Oldest' Value='OLD' />" &_
    " <Option Code='N' Description='Newest' Value='NEW' />" &_
   "    </Options>" &_
  "</Parameter>" &_
 "</Parameters>"
End Function

'Parameter Variables
Dim Age : Set Age = Parameters.Item( Bookmark , "Age" )

' PlaceHolder Variables
Dim CommentNodes

''' stop here and look around
stop

Select Case Age.Value
 Case "OLD":
  Set CommentNodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/ServiceEvent[0]/Service/Comment")
 Case "NEW":
  Set CommentNodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/ServiceEvent[last()]/Service/Comment")
End Select

For Each CommentNode In CommentNodes
 ReturnData = ReturnData & CommentNode.Text & MD
Next

If Len(ReturnData) > 0 Then
 ReturnData = Left(ReturnData, Len(ReturnData) - Len(MD))
Else
 ReturnData = vbNullString 
End If
```

for some reason it doesn't like `last()`  is there another way to do this?  I need the functionality of the last function, so that if there is only one `ServiceEvent` node it will still grab that node.

---

I am not a VBScript Guy (*yet*) and everything that I have learned about xPath is what I have learned on the job.

Comment: I have the complete working code now posted on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/37254/18427)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the following property

```
XmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

My test xml is as follows

```
<root>
    <child1>
        <child2>
            <child3>test1</child3>
        </child2>
        <child2>
            <child3>test2</child3>
        </child2>
        <child2>
            <child3>test3</child3>
        </child2>
        <child2>
            <child3>test4</child3>
        </child2>
    </child1>
</root>
```

My test code is as follows

```
strXMLReadFile = "C:\Test.xml"

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.Load(strXMLReadFile)

Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//root/child1/child2[last()]")
msgbox nodeXML(0).Text
```

I get `test4`

Comment: I did have to change the index of the other XPath query from `[0]` to `[1]` but other than that it worked nicely, I wasn't sure how it would interact with other pieces of the application. but I think it should be fine now.  I am going to have to note this for future tokens, I think I can clean the code of a few of them using this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeNode[position() = last()]
```

is what you want.

Comment: doesn't like that either, same error except it errors out at `position()` instead of `last()`

Comment: this worked, but wasn't necessary after I had the property set for the document.