# Extract XML value from file using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xml-parsing

Please believe me, I **really** have googled and searched, but I'm a newbie to XML using VBA. All the examples I've seen use what I would call "simple" XML, and my example (to me) seems more complicated. First of all, here's a simple extract of my XML (if I can manage to append it with block quotes).

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns1="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin">
   <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema xmlns="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types">
         <xsd:element name="checkTin">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="FR" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:element name="98-0242041" type="xsd:string" />
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
         <xsd:element name="checkTinResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="countryCode" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:element name="tinNumber" type="xsd:string" />
                  "
                  <xsd:element name="requestDate" type="xsd:date" />
                  <xsd:element name="validStructure" type="xsd:boolean" />
                  <xsd:element name="validSyntax" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
        .... multiple elements of <xsd:element name="checkTin"> and <xsd:element >  name="checkTinResponse"> then follow
        .....
      </xsd:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="checkTinRequest">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns1:checkTin" />
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="checkTinResponse">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns1:checkTinResponse" />
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="checkTinPortType">
      <wsdl:operation name="checkTin">
         <wsdl:input name="checkTinRequest" message="impl:checkTinRequest" />
         <wsdl:output name="checkTinResponse" message="impl:checkTinResponse" />
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="checkTinBinding" type="impl:checkTinPortType">
      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
      <wsdl:operation name="checkTin">
         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
         <wsdl:input name="checkTinRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output name="checkTinResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="checkTinService">
      <wsdl:port name="checkTinPort" binding="impl:checkTinBinding">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/tin/services/checkTinService" />
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I have found and tested the following code:

```
Public Sub LoadDocument()

Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
XDoc.validateOnParse = False
' The file here is basically the same as the XML code above
If XDoc.Load("E:\Excel\TIN\KVKF440I.txt") Then
   ' The document loaded successfully.
   ' Now do something intersting.
   DisplayNode XDoc.ChildNodes, 0
Else
   ' The document failed to load.
   ' See the previous listing for error information.
   ' The document failed to load.
   Dim strErrText As String
   Dim xPE As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError
   ' Obtain the ParseError object
   Set xPE = XDoc.parseError
   With xPE
      strErrText = "Your XML Document failed to load" & _
            "due the following error." & vbCrLf & _
      "Error #: " & .ErrorCode & ": " & xPE.reason & _
      "Line #: " & .Line & vbCrLf & _
      "Line Position: " & .linepos & vbCrLf & _
      "Position In File: " & .filepos & vbCrLf & _
      "Source Text: " & .srcText & vbCrLf & _
      "Document URL: " & .URL
    End With

    MsgBox strErrText, vbExclamation
End If

Set XDoc = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub DisplayNode(ByRef Nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, ByVal Indent    As Integer)

   Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
   Indent = Indent + 2

   For Each xNode In Nodes
     ' If xNode.NodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
       If xNode.ParentNode.nodeName = "xsd:element" Then
         Debug.Print Space$(Indent) & xNode.ParentNode.nodeName & _
             ":" & xNode.NodeValue
       End If

       If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
         DisplayNode xNode.ChildNodes, Indent
       End If
   Next xNode

End Sub
```

Basically, I want to loop (?) for each `element name="checkTin"`
and extract the values for the child `element name=` 
(ie, in the example above, I want to extract FR and 98-0242021). 
Then I want to do the same thing do the same thing for the corresponding 
`element name="checkTinResponse"` and extract the 5 elements of 
`xsd:element name=` that belong to this.

As I say, I have tried loads of examples I found, but obviously I don't know what I'm doing, nor do I completely understand that results I'm getting.
For example, I'm guessing that the copied code above that tests for `xNode.ParentNode.nodeName = "xsd:element"` is not really the best way to go.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XPath` expressions to get the elements you are looking for.

I have used 2 `XPath` expressions in the code below:

- `//*[local-name()='schema']/*[local-name()='element']`
- `././/*[local-name()='element']`

`//*[local-name()='schema']/*[local-name()='element']` is used get all the `elements` under the `schema` node. Then we loop each element and use the `XPath` expression `././/*[local-name()='element']` to get the child `elements`.

**NB:** Before executing the procedure, add reference to `Microsoft Xml, v6.0`.

```
Sub GetElements()
    Dim xmlFileName As String
    Dim XDoc As DOMDocument60
    Dim pElements As IXMLDOMNodeList, pElement As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim chElements As IXMLDOMNodeList, chElement As IXMLDOMNode

    xmlFileName = "C:\Temp\test.xml"       ''-- set filename appropriately
    Set XDoc = New DOMDocument60
    XDoc.validateOnParse = False
    If XDoc.Load(xmlFileName) Then
       ''-- The document loaded successfully.
       Set pElements = XDoc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='schema']/*[local-name()='element']")
       For Each pElement In pElements
            ''-- print the parent node
            Debug.Print pElement.Attributes.getNamedItem("name").NodeValue
            Set chElements = pElement.SelectNodes("././/*[local-name()='element']")
            For Each chElement In chElements
                ''-- print the child nodes
                Debug.Print vbTab & chElement.Attributes.getNamedItem("name").NodeValue
            Next
       Next
    Else
       ''-- The document failed to load.
        MsgBox Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
    End If

    Set XDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

**RESULT :**

> ```
> checkTin
>     FR
>     98-0242041
> checkTinResponse
>     countryCode
>     tinNumber
>     requestDate
>     validStructure
>     validSyntax
> ```

Comment: Many thanks. There's **no** way I'd have made it to that solution. I'll test later tonight at home.

Comment: I had to change the code to `Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument` and `Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument`, but on the line with `Set pElements = XDoc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='schema']/*[local-name()='element']")` I got an error message of "Unknown method"

Comment: Found the solution here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617236/unknown-method-in-xpath-run-by-vbscript I added the line about SetProperty and then it workd fine. Many thanks for your original answer

Comment: The above code should run fine as it is if you add reference to `Microsoft Xml, v6.0`, as stated in the answer. You probably added reference to a lower version DLL.