# Read text from a TextBox shape (in a specific Sheet) of a CLOSED Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

**Scenario:**

1. You have an Excel file (*a.xlsm*) with one single sheet (*Sheet1*).
2. In this sheet there's a text-box shape (*Text1*) with text (e.g.: "this is my text").

[image]

[image]

[Download file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/yic3708dl5znbla/a.zip/file)

---

**Goal:**

How would one achieve in VBA reading the content of *Text1* **without opening *a.xlsm* Excel file**?

---

**Not allowed:**

- the use of *Workbooks.Open*
- the use of *Excel.Application* to open the file in the background, visible or not visible

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Excel files are ZIP archives. If you rename one such file to .zip extension, you will see you can open it and explore its content. I am using *WinRAR* here to view *a.zip*'s content (I have renamed a.xlsm -> a.zip):

[image]

If you now extract the content of the archive to disk, you will find that in **xl** folder there's a sub-folder called **drawings**. In here, there's a file called **drawings1.xml**. Our *Text1* text-box from *Sheet1* is a 'drawing'. Reviewing the file in a text editor:

[image]

---

So the logic I thought of to achieve reading " **this is my text** " works like this:

- allow the user to select the input Excel file (any .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm)

  - preferable is the input file is in the same location as the processor
- create a copy of this file, renamed as *.zip*: a.xlsm -> a.zip
- extract *drawing1.xml* file to disk from *xl\drawings\* path inside a.zip
- parse the .xml file to extract the text
- remove the extracted .xml file and .zip copy when done

---

The VBA code is included in *mod_GetShapeTextFromClosedFile* of the file below:

[Download file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/x3a5zds4usw6ick/b.zip/file)

---

First-up, the following **Tools** > **References** are required (already enabled in the attached file):

- Microsoft Scripting Runtime (for *FileSystemObject*)
- Microsoft XML, v6.0 (for *DOMDocument60*)

---

Next, explaining the code snippets matching the bullets I've detailed in the process logic.

- allow the user to select the Excel file (defaulting to **current directory**):

```
    sDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path: ChDrive (Left(sDir, 1)): ChDir (sDir)
    FilePathName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm), *.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", FilterIndex:=2, MultiSelect:=False)
```

- making a copy of the input file so it has a .zip extension:

```
    FilePath = Left(FilePathName, InStrRev(FilePathName, "\") - 1)
    ZIPFilePathName = FilePath & "\" & "a.zip"
    fso.CopyFile FilePathName, ZIPFilePathName, True
```

- extracting 'xl\drawings\drawing1.xml' from the .zip

```
    FilePath = Left(FilePathName, InStrRev(FilePathName, "\") - 1)
    ZIPFilePathName = FilePath & "\" & "a.zip"
    ExtractFile ZIPFilePathName, FilePath, "xl\drawings\drawing1.xml"
```

- walking XML XPaths to the Nodes of interest, reading the text and populating A2 and A3 cells:

```
    i = 2
    Set pElements = XDoc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='twoCellAnchor']")
    For Each pElement In pElements
        Set chElements = pElement.SelectNodes("././/*[local-name()='t']")
        For Each chElement In chElements
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value2 = chElement.Text
            i = i + 1
        Next chElement
    Next pElement
```

- removing the .xml and .zip (clean-up)

```
    fso.DeleteFile XMLFilePathName: fso.DeleteFile ZIPFilePathName
```

---

You can always use [XPath Generator Online](https://www.easycodeforall.com/generate-xpath.html) to paste in your XML and obtain the paths:

```
/xdr:wsDr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:clientData
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:from
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:from/xdr:col
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:from/xdr:colOff
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:from/xdr:row
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:from/xdr:rowOff
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/@macro
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/@textlink
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:nvSpPr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:nvSpPr/xdr:cNvPr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:nvSpPr/xdr:cNvPr/@id
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:nvSpPr/xdr:cNvPr/@name
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:nvSpPr/xdr:cNvSpPr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:nvSpPr/xdr:cNvSpPr/@txBox
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:ln
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:ln/@cmpd
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:ln/@w
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:ln/a:solidFill
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:ln/a:solidFill/a:schemeClr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:ln/a:solidFill/a:schemeClr/@val
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:ln/a:solidFill/a:schemeClr/a:shade
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:ln/a:solidFill/a:schemeClr/a:shade/@val
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:prstGeom
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:prstGeom/@prst
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:prstGeom/a:avLst
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:solidFill
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:solidFill/a:schemeClr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:solidFill/a:schemeClr/@val
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:xfrm
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:xfrm/a:ext
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:xfrm/a:ext/@cx
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:xfrm/a:ext/@cy
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:xfrm/a:off
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:xfrm/a:off/@x
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:xfrm/a:off/@y
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:effectRef
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:effectRef/@idx
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:effectRef/a:scrgbClr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:effectRef/a:scrgbClr/@b
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:effectRef/a:scrgbClr/@g
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:effectRef/a:scrgbClr/@r
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:fillRef
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:fillRef/@idx
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:fillRef/a:scrgbClr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:fillRef/a:scrgbClr/@b
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:fillRef/a:scrgbClr/@g
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:fillRef/a:scrgbClr/@r
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:fontRef
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:fontRef/@idx
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:fontRef/a:schemeClr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:fontRef/a:schemeClr/@val
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:lnRef
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:lnRef/@idx
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:lnRef/a:scrgbClr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:lnRef/a:scrgbClr/@b
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:lnRef/a:scrgbClr/@g
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:style/a:lnRef/a:scrgbClr/@r
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:bodyPr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:bodyPr/@anchor
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:bodyPr/@horzOverflow
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:bodyPr/@rtlCol
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:bodyPr/@vertOverflow
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:bodyPr/@wrap
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:lstStyle
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:endParaRPr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:endParaRPr/@lang
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:endParaRPr/@sz
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:rPr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:rPr/@lang
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:rPr/@sz
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r[2]
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r[2]/a:rPr
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r[2]/a:rPr/@baseline
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r[2]/a:rPr/@lang
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r[2]/a:rPr/@sz
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r[2]/a:t
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:to
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:to/xdr:col
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:to/xdr:colOff
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:to/xdr:row
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:to/xdr:rowOff
```

As well as test them:

```
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t    -> this is my
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor/xdr:sp/xdr:txBody/a:p/a:r[2]/a:t -> text
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

Best regards.

**EDIT:**

Full VBA code for people who think file(s) will be purged by the hosting site:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Sub GetShapeTextFromClosedFile()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim sDir As String: sDir = ""
    Dim FilePathName As Variant: FilePathName = False
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = ""
    Dim ZIPFilePathName As String: ZIPFilePathName = ""
    Dim XMLFilePathName As String: XMLFilePathName = ""
    
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim ts As TextStream, data As Variant, s As String, i As Long, j As Long
    
    Dim XDoc As DOMDocument60: Set XDoc = New DOMDocument60
    Dim pElements As IXMLDOMNodeList, pElement As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim chElements As IXMLDOMNodeList, chElement As IXMLDOMNode
    
    sDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path: ChDrive (Left(sDir, 1)): ChDir (sDir)
    FilePathName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm), *.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", FilterIndex:=2, MultiSelect:=False)

    If FilePathName = False Then
        MsgBox "Invalid file or user cancelled."
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
'--
' Use FileSystemObject to copy the dummy report as a ZIP file
'--

    FilePath = Left(FilePathName, InStrRev(FilePathName, "\") - 1)
    ZIPFilePathName = FilePath & "\" & "a.zip"
    XMLFilePathName = FilePath & "\" & "drawing1.xml"
    
    fso.CopyFile FilePathName, ZIPFilePathName, True
     
'--
' Extract 'xl\drawings\drawing1.xml' to current folder
'--

    ExtractFile ZIPFilePathName, FilePath, "xl\drawings\drawing1.xml"
    
'--
' Open 'drawing1.xml' as XML and parse it
'--
    
    'https://jsonformatter.org/xml-formatter
    'https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-read-data-from-xml-file/
    'https://analystcave.com/vba-xml-working-xml-files/
    
    'XPath:
    'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp
    'https://www.easycodeforall.com/generate-xpath.html
    
'--
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891403/extract-xml-value-from-file-using-vba
' Credit: Pradeep Kumar (thanks for the example!)
'--
    
    XDoc.async = False: XDoc.validateOnParse = False
    XDoc.Load (XMLFilePathName)
    
    i = 2
    Set pElements = XDoc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='twoCellAnchor']")
    For Each pElement In pElements
        Set chElements = pElement.SelectNodes("././/*[local-name()='t']")
        For Each chElement In chElements
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value2 = chElement.Text
            i = i + 1
        Next chElement
    Next pElement

'--
' Remove 'drawing1.xml' file and 'a.xlsm'
'--

    fso.DeleteFile XMLFilePathName: fso.DeleteFile ZIPFilePathName
          
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox _
    "Error in module: mod_GetShapeTextFromClosedFile" & vbNewLine & _
    "Macro: GetShapeTextFromClosedFile" & vbNewLine & _
    "Error Message: " & Err.Description & String$(1, vbTab) & vbNewLine & _
    "Error Number: " & Err.Number & _
    vbCritical, _
    "Error"

End Sub

Private Function ExtractFile(ByVal strZipFilename, ByVal strDstDir, ByVal strFilename)

'--
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716587/how-to-open-a-file-from-an-archive-in-vba-without-unzipping-the-archive/19725357
' Credit: jacouh for this nifty function
'--

    Dim objShell, objSource, objTarget
    
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objSource = objShell.Namespace(strZipFilename).Items.Item(CStr(strFilename))
    Set objTarget = objShell.Namespace(strDstDir)
    
    objTarget.CopyHere objSource, 16 'Respond with "Yes to All" for any dialog box that is displayed.
                                     'Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere
    
    Set objSource = Nothing: Set objTarget = Nothing: Set objShell = Nothing
  
End Function
```

Comment: The files are uploaded to my personal MediaFire account (not an anonymous account). So.. until I delete my account or MediaFire goes out of business. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I was just thinking that this answer would be better if it were self contained and not dependent on an external site/file that may not exist in the future for whatever reason. MediaFire does purge inactive users, so I guess everyone in the future will just have to hope that you keep your account active?

Comment: I have added the full VBA code at the bottom of my solution. Cheers.